# Expanding the allowed HTML tags in comments?

Tags: comments, user-roles, permissions

I have no problem doing this in a comment, as an administrator:

```
<b>bold test</b> <i>italics test</i>
<u>underline test</u> <font
color="#ff9900"> color test</font>
```

But the subscribers can't underline, add color to words nor add images.

Is it that only the admin can use more HTML tags than those suggested under the comment form?

```
<a href="" title=""> <abbr title="">
<acronym title=""> <b> <blockquote
cite=""> <cite> <code> <del
datetime=""> <em> <i> <q cite="">
<strike> <strong>
```

How to enable the subscribers to add color to text, and add images?

Comment: How about using roles to acchieve this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags that are allowed in comments are stored in [the `$allowedtags` global variable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/kses.php#L397). You can try adding elements to that list (the key is the tag name, the value is an array of allowed attributes). If you have problems with the timing you can play with [the `CUSTOM_TAGS` global variable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/kses.php#L34).

Answer (score 3):

I too needed to customise the list of available HTML tags in comments. I didn't want to define the `CUSTOM_TAGS` variable because it overrides everything that WP sets up in [`kses.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L0), but I wasn't sure where to hook the function. A little investigation showed that [`kses.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L0) initialises its filters via [`kses_init()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L1423) which is added as a function to 'init' with the default priority of 10, so...

```
/*
 * customise list of allowed HTML tags in comments
 */
function gregory_customise_allowedTags() {

    global $allowedtags;

    // remove unwanted tags
    $unwanted = array(
        'abbr',
        'acronym',
        'blockquote',
        'cite',
        'code',
        'del',
        'strike',
        'strong'
        );
    foreach ( $unwanted as $tag )
        unset( $allowedtags[$tag] );

    // add wanted tags
    $newTags = array(
        'span' => array(
            'lang' => array()),
        'u' => array()
        );
    $allowedtags = array_merge( $allowedtags, $newTags );

}

add_action('init', 'gregory_customise_allowedTags', 11 );
```

Reference:

- [/wp-includes/kses.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L0)
- Look at the first section where `$allowedtags` is defined.
- Look at [kses_init()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/kses.php#L1423) and its accompanying add_action commands.

Answer (score 0):

**Just more exmple :**

```
function allow_tags_content() {
    global $allowedposttags, $allowedtags;

    $allowedposttags['div']['data-hello'] = true;
    $allowedtags['div']['data-hello'] = true;

    $allowedposttags['div']['data-world'] = true;
    $allowedtags['div']['data-world'] = true;
}
add_action('init','allow_tags_content');
```