# How to allow more HTML tags in comment for a certain comment_type

Tags: comments

I'm using a custom comment_type for my plugin and that comment type is connected to only a custom post_type. And now I want to add the TinyMCE Editor to the comment section, and want to allow more tags than typical, especially some headings, pre tag, and ordered & unordered lists. But adding an editor to the comment section is the half part of it. I need to allow those tags to bypass the wp_kses for the comment content.

I did something earlier, that seems foolish now:

```
$response_msg = wp_kses( $response_msg, my_allowed_html() );

$comment_id = wp_new_comment( array(
    'comment_post_ID'       => absint( $post->ID )   ,
    'comment_author'        => wp_strip_all_tags( $current_user->display_name ),
    'comment_author_email'  => sanitize_email( $current_user->user_email ),
    'comment_author_url'    => esc_url( $current_user->user_url ),
    'comment_content'       => $response_msg,
    'comment_type'          => 'wpse_response',
    'comment_parent'        => 0,
    'user_id'               => absint( $current_user->ID ),
) );
```

Because even though the `my_allowed_html()` function passes newly allowed HTML to the comment section, the `wp_new_comment()`, with its inherited filter will `wp_kses()` all of 'em to the defaults. So that's foolish.

I figured out that [this solution](https://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-comment-tags) is not a good one, as of now (WP v5.2.1) `comment_post` would be too late to hook for this. The correct code for doing this would be what [Milan Petrovic suggested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/280574/22728):

```
function wpse20190615_allowed_html_in_responses($comment_content)
{
    global $allowedtags;

    $allowedtags['pre'] = array('class'=>array());
    $allowedtags['h2'] = array();
    $allowedtags['h3'] = array();
    $allowedtags['h4'] = array();
    $allowedtags['h5'] = array();
    $allowedtags['h6'] = array();
    $allowedtags['ul'] = array();
    $allowedtags['ol'] = array();
    $allowedtags['li'] = array();

    return $comment_content;
}

add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wpse20190615_allowed_html_in_responses', 9 );
```

But what I understand is, this filter will allow these HTML tags into all the comments, including the default comments for posts, pages. I want to allow these HTML tags restricted to only the comments of my comment_type (or my post type).

I tried with [the `init` hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73966/22728) but seems `global $post` and `$post->post_type` detection might be too earlier, so eventually not worthy for my case.

And `pre_comment_content` allows only a single parameter and that doesn't have the information about the comment type also.

So, **how can I restrict the code above to a certain comment_type**, something like:

```
function wpse20190615_allowed_html_in_responses($comment_content)
{
    // if('wpse_response' !== $comment->comment_type) {
    //     return $comment_content;
    // }

    global $allowedtags;
    ...

    return $comment_content;
}

add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wpse20190615_allowed_html_in_responses', 9 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested but should work since it gives you the data you need to work from and runs prior to the `pre_comment_content` filter where the comment is sanitized.

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpse_340526_preprocess_comment' );

function wpse_340526_preprocess_comment( $commentdata ) {
    if( 'wpse_response' === $commentdata['comment_type'] ){
        global $allowedtags;
        $allowedtags['pre'] = array('class'=>array());
        $allowedtags['h2'] = array();
        $allowedtags['h3'] = array();
        $allowedtags['h4'] = array();
        $allowedtags['h5'] = array();
        $allowedtags['h6'] = array();
        $allowedtags['ul'] = array();
        $allowedtags['ol'] = array();
        $allowedtags['li'] = array();
    }

    return $commentdata;
}
```

Comment: I’m embarrassed to admit I had to edit this a few too many times, but it looks good now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I missed that `preprocess_comment` purposefully because I thought that would be overridden by the `wp_filter_comment()` later. But that was my mistake. Thanks a lot.